Is this multicollinearity, and how can I specify my model better?
I'm analyzing data from the usual care period only of a stepped wedge cluster-randomized trial. The goal is to describe the usual care period as though it was a cohort study because much higher fidelity data about participants and outcomes were collected than are available otherwise. The outcome will be the same as the trial's, and the exposures of interest will be the collected baseline covariates.
The trial studied an intervention to prevent hospital-acquired infection and ten hospitals participated. Each row of data represents a hospital admission. Because some patients were hospitalized more than once, I have specified a random effect for the patients. Because we are interested in hospital-level variation, I have included each hospital as a fixed effect (factor variable). The current model, which converges, looks like this:
m0 <- gam(infection ~ 
            age + sex + had_surgery + hospital_id + s(patient_id, bs="re"), 
            data=df, 
            family="binomial")

However, I would like to incorporate the step variable from the stepped wedge trial design as a covariate to account for possible secular trends during the study period. Because I have no expectation that infection rates would vary linearly with time, I've coded step as a factor. When I add this to the above model, it fails to converge.
I suspect this has something to do with multicollinearity as the crosstabs of hospital_id vs. step look like this (by virtue of the stepped wedge design - recall we have data from the usual care period only):
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 1 183  73  92  66  23  64  23  46  38  88
 2 284 934 639 937 837 777 374 256 356   0
 3  92  37  35  95  85  47  72  37   0   0
 4  17  78  23  40  11  93  28   0   0   0
 5 123 345 685 234 203 111   0   0   0   0
 6  34  22  15  32  99   0   0   0   0   0
 7  32  94  23  15   0   0   0   0   0   0
 8 175 633  17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 9 239  34   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10 374   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

When I include step as a continuous variable instead of a factor, the model converges without issue—I have no intention of doing this in the final model (it doesn't make sense to me to interpret the variable that way), but it suggests to me that something about the categorical nature of step is driving the convergence issues. Am I on the right track? Given the structure of the data and the goal of the analysis, what is a better way to do this?

Why are you using gam for your model? Typically GAMs are used for nonlinear terms, and it doesn't appear you have set up any splines in your model (other than the random effect term spline, which just estimates random intercepts). Also it appear there are 10 hospital IDs from my best guess here. Is there a reason you haven't specified this also as a random effect? I assume it's not a fixed effect of interest for your model. I would think patients would be nested in hospitals here as well.

mgcv::gam can be used to fit models with random intercepts and is generally much faster than lme4 for large datasets (we have about 50k observations in the real dataset, sorry the above examples are from toy data; see https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-10-20-big-mixed-models/). Hospital is a fixed effect of interest in our model, patients are not nested in hospitals (they can be admitted to different hospitals at different times).

If your objective was speed, wouldn't bam be a better candidate? Otherwise what you said makes sense (I was secretly curious if patients went to multiple hospitals). Unfortunately I have no expertise on the method you describe ("stepped wedge cluster-randomized trial"), so I can't offer any other advice there.
